# Remove message shown each time ZSH runs (with oh-my-zsh installed)

Tags: command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I decided to slim down my `.zshrc` and declutter `oh-my-zsh` entries. It seems that `zsh` can now auto install referenced plugins and auto update them, which was something I wanted to achieved.  However, every time I run terminal I get the following output:

```
[zplug] Start to update 0 plugins in parallel


[zplug] Elapsed time: 0.0074 sec.
 ==> Updating finished successfully!
```

**It is of course not needed and I'd like it to be removed.**

Here's the section of `.zshrc` where I have `oh-my-zsh` entries:

```bsh
# Check if zplug is installed
[ ! -d ~/.zplug ] && git clone https://github.com/zplug/zplug ~/.zplug
source ~/.zplug/init.zsh && zplug update

zplug 'zplug/zplug',    hook-build:'zplug --self-manage'
zplug "seebi/dircolors-solarized", ignore:"*", as:plugin
zplug "plugins/mvn",    from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/gradle", from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/git",    from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/sudo",   from:oh-my-zsh
zplug "plugins/dnf",    from:oh-my-zsh

# Supports checking out a specific branch/tag/commit
zplug "b4b4r07/enhancd", at:v1

# Support bitbucket
zplug "b4b4r07/hello_bitbucket", \
    from:bitbucket, \
    as:command, \
    use:"*.sh"

zplug "zsh-users/zsh-completions",              defer:0
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions",          defer:2, on:"zsh-users/zsh-completions"
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting",      defer:3, on:"zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions"
zplug "zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search", defer:3, on:"zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting"

# Install plugins if there are plugins that have not been installed
if ! zplug check --verbose; then
    printf "Install? [y/N]: "
    if read -q; then
        echo; zplug install
    fi
fi

# Then, source plugins and add commands to $PATH
zplug load
```

Comment: I don't use it, but if I was to guess, I would comment out the `source ~/.zplug/init.zsh && zplug update` line...

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am not using it either, but I would expect that commenting out that line would result in a lot of error messages about there not being a `zplug` command. Instead I would just remove the `&& zplug update` part because I think it is debatable, whether automatic updates everytime a `zsh` session is started are even a *Good Idea*™.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on reviewing the code at https://github.com/zplug/zplug, those messages are emitted by zplug to stdout via printf, so you could silence them by changing this line:

```
source ~/.zplug/init.zsh && zplug update
```

to this one:

```
source ~/.zplug/init.zsh && zplug update > /dev/null
```

To inhibit the update altogether, simply remove the update command:

```
source ~/.zplug/init.zsh
```